# Hibernate find with composite key. Invalid column name Exception

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to do a Hibernate Find using a composite Primary key but keep getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Invalid column name 'merchantNumberAccountTypeId'.
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2033)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3720)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1079)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2200(SessionImpl.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:975)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:807)
    ... 30 more
```

I can persist an `Entity` with no problems but can't retrieve one (I have also tried to create a query directly but I get the same issue).

My `Entity` class looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class MerchantNumberAccountType implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private MerchantNumberAccountTypeId merchantNumberAccountTypeId;

    public MerchantNumberAccountTypeId getMerchantNumberAccountTypeId() {
        return merchantNumberAccountTypeId;
    }

    public void setMerchantNumberAccountTypeId(MerchantNumberAccountTypeId merchantNumberAccountTypeId) {
        this.merchantNumberAccountTypeId = merchantNumberAccountTypeId;
    }

    @Embeddable
    public static class MerchantNumberAccountTypeId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Column
        public String merchantNumber;
        @Column
        public String accountType;

        public MerchantNumberAccountTypeId(){

        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object other){
            if(this == other){
                return true;
            }
            if (!(other instanceof MerchantNumberAccountTypeId)) {
                return false;
            }
            MerchantNumberAccountTypeId otherAccTypeId = (MerchantNumberAccountTypeId) other;

            return this.merchantNumber.equals(otherAccTypeId.merchantNumber) && this.accountType.equals(otherAccTypeId.accountType);

        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode(){
            return merchantNumber.hashCode() + accountType.hashCode();
        }

        public String getMerchantNumber() {
            return merchantNumber;
        }

        public void setMerchantNumber(String merchantNumber) {
            this.merchantNumber = merchantNumber;
        }

        public String getAccountType() {
            return accountType;
        }

        public void setAccountType(String accountType) {
            this.accountType = accountType;
        }
    }

}
```

**Update:**

I've found a workaround for this. I changed from using @EmbeddedId strategy to @IdClass. But when I did this I was getting the following error when the EnitityManagerFactory was being instantiated - Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [tblmerchantnumberaccounttype] contains logical column name [accountType] referenced by multiple physical column names: [id.accountType], [identifierMapper.accountType]. To prevent the physical columns getting id and identifierMapper appended to the front of them. (Can anyone please tell me why this is happening?) I annotated accountType & merchant number in my Id class with @Column(value="AccountType) & @Column(value="MerchantNumber"), if you just have @Column without the value attribute it still fails. It was still failing after this because now the physical column names were getting and underscore aded before a capital letter. i.e AccountType became account_type. To get around this I can either override the columnName method in ImprovedNamingStrategy with my own version that doesn't add the underscores or I can simply have @Column(value="accounttype") instead. Can anyone explain to me what's going on here? Many thanks.

**Update 2:**
The @EmbeddedId way works too. The important thing annotating the member variables in the Key Class and explicitly giving them the column name (with no caps!).

Comment: Have you tried defining the `@Embeddable` class in a separate file as a public class ?

Comment: Yeah tried that. Same result.

Comment: I don't like to see an unanswered question so I'll have a go at this one. Before I answer, can you post the code that is doing the actual find. Is it a JPQL query, or an `em.find()`?

Comment: Perhaps related: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9114?focusedCommentId=63453&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-63453

Comment: Filed a bug report: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9350

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem.
I solved it using the **@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns**, try this (from another example):

```
@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(value = {
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "country_code"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "zip_code", referencedColumnName = "code")
})
private Zip zip;

@ManyToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumns(value = {
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "country_code"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "state_code", referencedColumnName = "state_code"),
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "city_name", referencedColumnName = "name")
})
private City city;
```

from [Hibernate throws AnnotationException on column used by multiple overlapping foreign keys](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6221)