# How to inherit @Id from mapped superclass?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to create a `primary composite key` and use an `@Id` field from a parent class. But it does not work. Why?

```
@MappedSuperclass
static abstract class SuperEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(SuperPK.class)
public static class ChildEntity extends SuperEntity {
    @Id
    private String lang;
}


public class SuperPK {
    public SuperPK(Long id, String lang) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Result: `Property of @IdClass not found in entity ChildEntity: id`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composite Key in JPA / Hibernate with inherited class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216102/composite-key-in-jpa-hibernate-with-inherited-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an [open issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9114) regarding this bug.

One of the comments states to override the getters for the ID properties as a workaround.

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SuperPK.class)
public static class ChildEntity extends SuperEntity {
    @Id
    private String lang;

    @Override @Id
    public Long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }
}
```